# Disabling browser front and back buttons on Sales force lightning communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community, lightning

I have a requirement where in we need to restrict user from navigating by clicking browser front and back button in communities lightning pages.

I found that we can use the below code from disabling back button on browser

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack()
    {
        window.history.forward();
    }
  </script>
  <body onLoad="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onUnload="">
```

however, my question is , how can we call it directly rather than creating refering external js in static resource inside  tag?

Comment: Please post your current code. That helps in understanding

Comment: @AnuragA - JS code posted above with the question